# Disk Usage format

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

How can I get the disk usage information that is in human readable format `-h option` but is also sorted correctly.

Right now if i use `-h option` it does not get sorted correctly i.e G M K are not in ascending order.

Comment: [how do you sort du output by size?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4681)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question. Why isn't is not sorted?

**edit** should ask for the same unit, e.g. always kilobytes with `du -k`

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ du -k ./* | sort -nr
120K    ./GTP
108K    ./scripts
 36K    ./backup
 24K    ./GTP/ParserDump
 20K    ./perl
4.0K    ./outfile
4.0K    ./file1
4.0K    ./file
4.0K    ./colors
4.0K    ./GTP/ParserDump/ParserDump
```

If you need to output using "human friendly" units, make the conversion after sorting (perhaps using `awk`).

**AWK Script:** This is how we can sort the files .. don't know if we can using the `-h option` but this is kinda like simulating the `-h option`. Results are more accurate ;)

```
[jaypal~/Desktop/Reference]$ du -h ./* | sort -nr
584K    ./scan 1.pdf
544K    ./Personal/Resume
 44K    ./Membership.xlsx
 16M    ./Personal
 16K    ./Membership Transmittal Template.xlsx
 14M    ./Personal/Docs
2.4M    ./Work Docs
1.6M    ./Work Docs/Work
1.5M    ./Personal/Raa

[jaypal~/Desktop/Reference]$ du -k ./* | sort -nr | awk '{split("KB,MB,GB",size,",");}{x = 1;while ($1 >= 1024) {$1 = $1 / 1024;x = x + 1} $1 = sprintf("%-4.2f%s", $1, size[x]); print $0;}'
15.92MB ./Personal
13.82MB ./Personal/Docs
2.35MB ./Work Docs
1.59MB ./Work Docs/Work
1.46MB ./Personal/Raa
584.00KB ./scan 1.pdf
544.00KB ./Personal/Resume
44.00KB ./Membership.xlsx
16.00KB ./Membership Transmittal Template.xlsx
```

Comment: perhaps because the unit varies between K & M ? Then using `du -k` should always give kilobytes, so answers the question

Comment: Yep, I agree. You should have answered this. It was a better answer than mine. :)

Comment: Unless, I get it to sort with `-h option` ;)

Comment: I've edited your answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks Basile, I added the AWK script. :)

Answer (score 5):

Using [GNU Coreutils >= 7.5](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sort-invocation):

```
du -hs * | sort -h
```

On Mac OS X it's easy to install coreutils with homebrew:

```
sudo brew install coreutils
```

From https://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size

Comment: Great!! I didn't know that sort `-h` compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)

Comment: Damn! I didn't know that either. Good Info!! Thanks Dave!